# Radare2 - recursive traversal visual mode

Tags: disassembly, radare2

I know that both `pdf @ func` and `pdr @ func` disassemble the function, the first using linear and the second recursive traversal disassembly. `VV @ func` shows the disassembled function in visual mode, but it seems it uses linear sweep. Can I use recursive traversal and see the output in visual mode?